# Saving added GeoJSON data in the browser for future use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, http, qgis-browser

I have managed to add a GeoJSON layer to QGIS via an HTTP protocol in my local machine. How can I save the connection in the browser so I can access it in other QGIS projects?

Below is a sample URL I used:

https://localhost/rest/services/api/geroserver/find?layer=rivers.fill&searchText=ch&searchField=id&returnGeometry=true&geometryFormat=geojson

(The above link is just for demo purposes only, it serves as an example. I cannot share the real link)

Comment: Can you just use wfs in the browser? like https://www.lifeingis.com/adding-layers-from-geoserver-in-qgis/ (include port number)

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz in a real work scenario, your approach is correct to follow. I am just looking at other possibilities which I have managed to achieve some of them, I am looking into ways to keep them in my QGIS environment without having to reload them manually all the time. It is like putting a helicopter engine into a bike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save it as a layer definition file (*.qlr).

Example:

- I add [this geojson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Toblerity/Fiona/master/tests/data/grenada.geojson) to QGIS

  [image]
- I save as a layer definition

  [image]
- It's now available anytime in the browser

  [image]
- If I add the .qlr to QGIS from the browser, it is still pointing to the online GeoJSON

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to @user2856 answer, by adding the folder as a favorite folder, I could not only access to the .qlr file but also to the project and its content in terms of layers. See the picture below.:

[image]